# Apache2, Kerberos, SSI: how to login under another user

Tags: authentication, apache2, kerberos, single-sign-on

I have web-app with authorization by REMOTE_USER header. If apache2 + [mod_auth_kerb](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/) set REMOTE_USER by some ActiveDirectory username, my web-app know that user with such username is logged in. I have single sign on ([SSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Sign_In)) and it works perfect, but what should I do when I want to login as another user? How to force kerberos relogin (via basic auth, for example)?

If it isn't possible by mod_auth_kerb, but possible by some other apache (or nginx) mod, it is totally ok!

P.S. By the way, is it safe to rely on REMOTE_USER HTTP header in authorization process?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to log a user out if they were authenticated via browser-type basic auth.

Try using [Stanford WebAuth](http://webauth.stanford.edu/). This allows you to present an in-browser login page and still use the user's Kerberos creds (at your option using SPNEGO for a no-password login). It provides comprehensive logout functionality as well - the user's browser won't stop being authenticated Kerberos-wise, but it will stop being WebAuth logged-in.

It is safe to rely on the REMOTE_USER **server variable**. It is not an HTTP header - in PHP, it would be `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`, not `$_REQUEST['REMOTE_USER']`. It's set by server-side code.